# How to specify the subdataset query when executing report from a Java application

Tags: java, dataset, jasper-reports, report

I have a main report with a main query and a *Table* (with *subdataset*) inside of it, which has its own *Query*.

I know how to specify the *Query* for the main report, but I don't know how the to specify *Query* for the *subdatset* in my Java code of creation reports.

Can anyone help, please ?

My code:

```
public static java.sql.Connection cx = Connexion.SetConOn();

public static void Create report(String Query, String model, String title, String art) {
    try {
        JRDesignQuery jrd = new JRDesignQuery();
        JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(model);
        jrd.setText(Query);
        design.setQuery(jrd);
        Map map = new HashMap();
        JasperReport etat = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(etat, map, cx);
        File f = new File("C:\\" + fdg);
        f.mkdir();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, f.getPath() + "\\" + title + ".pdf");
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(print, false, Locale.FRENCH);

        try {
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(jv.getClass().getResource("/cycloplan/Images/Burn-icon1.png"));
            javax.swing.ImageIcon myImg = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(bi);
            jv.setIconImage(myImg.getImage());

        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        jv.setTitle(title);
        jv.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        jv.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JasperDesign` class has a few different ways to access subdatasets; take a look at the javadoc [[link]](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html). I think the following code should work to set the subdataset query, where `subQueryString` is the query you want to use and `datasetName` is the name given to  the subdataset element in the JRXML.

```
JRDesignQuery subQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
subQuery.setText(subQueryString);
Map<String, JRDataset> datasetMap = design.getDatasetMap();
JRDesignDataset subDataset = (JRDesignDataset) datasetMap.get(datasetName);
subDataset.setQuery(subQuery);
```

(* I haven't actually tested this code. YMMV)